# I have some trouble on Java source code about DefaultPersistenceDelegate

Tags: java

I just got some trouble with java source code for DefaultPersistenceDelegate, here is the code:

```
    /**
 * This default implementation of the <code>instantiate</code> method returns
 * an expression containing the predefined method name "new" which denotes a
 * call to a constructor with the arguments as specified in
 * the <code>DefaultPersistenceDelegate</code>'s constructor.
 *
 * @param  oldInstance The instance to be instantiated.
 * @param  out The code output stream.
 * @return An expression whose value is <code>oldInstance</code>.
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code out} is {@code null}
 *                              and this value is used in the method
 *
 * @see #DefaultPersistenceDelegate(String[])
 */
protected Expression instantiate(Object oldInstance, Encoder out) {
    int nArgs = constructor.length;
    Class<?> type = oldInstance.getClass();
    Object[] constructorArgs = new Object[nArgs];
    for(int i = 0; i < nArgs; i++) {
        try {
            Method method = findMethod(type, this.constructor[i]);
            constructorArgs[i] = MethodUtil.invoke(method, oldInstance, new Object[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            out.getExceptionListener().exceptionThrown(e);
        }
    }
    return new Expression(oldInstance, oldInstance.getClass(), "new", constructorArgs);
}
```

In the return statement , it returns a Expression with method name "new", but in my memory "new" should be a construct name,there is not a method named 'new'.

This question confuse me few days, is anybody can help me?

Comment: Sorry, the sentence _"..."new" should be a construct name not a method name"_ is not parseable in English.  The syntax looks completely valid, it is not clear what you don't understand.  `new Expression(...)` instantiates the object and invokes the constructor.

Comment: Nope....I try to get some example code of :                               
         Integer integer = 1;
        Expression aNew = new Expression(integer, "new", new Object[]{10});
        aNew.execute();
        System.out.println(aNew.getValue());    and it throw a Exception

Comment: When i try to call the Exception and got a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException